# Using add_table() method in openpyxl corrupts an existing excel file

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an existing excel file called "File.xlsx" with a sheet called "MySheet"

The data in MySheet is currently a range, I would like to open the excel file and convert the data in MySheet to an excel table. I am succesfully able to do this part, but when I open the excel file I get an error message that reads: *Repaired Records: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)*

**The script works in creating the table but I would like to avoid the excel file being unreadable error.**

The script I am using is here:

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

file_name = "File.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(file_name)
ws = wb['MySheet']
max_row = ws.max_row
max_column = ws.max_column

table = Table(displayName="FailureData", ref="A1:" + get_column_letter(max_column) + str(max_row))

ws.add_table(table)
wb.save(file_name)
wb.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error occurs when 2 header field has the same name. The solution is to make sure to have unique field names in the header by incrementing 1 on each duplication:

```
f = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Ford"]
print(f)
>>['Ford', 'Volvo', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Ford']

fields_out = [(x if i == f.index(x) else x + str(f.count(x) - f[i + 1:].count(x))) for i, x in enumerate(f)]
print(fields_out)
>>['Ford', 'Volvo', 'BMW', 'Ford2', 'Ford3']
```

For the same operation via the interface, Excel modifies the name of the duplicate fields.

*openpyxl version 3.0.5*

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It seems to be an issue with the older vesion of openpyxl, I was using version 2.6.1. I updated to the latest version 3.0.4 and the error no longer shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this having the same error.  My issue was that my table names started with numbers.  Excel doesn't like that apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a while, but for anyone else coming across this, I had a similar problem. The table had two columns with the same name. I dropped the duplicate column from the df and that resolved the issue.